# Does this cause memory leak?

Tags: c++

`Base` is the base class and `Derived` is the derived class.

```
Base* p = new Derived;
delete p;
```

Let's assume that the base destructor is not virtual. Does this cause memory leak, if yes, why? And what would be the solution to fix it?

Comment: It could but it will depend on the definition of the classes.  You will have to show those.

Comment: This is a duplicateeeeeeee

Comment: Let's assume that both the base and derived class have distinct dynamically allocated variables.

Comment: What do you think, @Southee? Will de-referencing a child cause the member data initialized in the parent to be deallocated? *well*?

Comment: @Southee Is this a homework or interview question, or do you have a practical problem to solve?

Answer (score 2):

It might.

It might not.

It might explode your computer.

It has *undefined behaviour*.

Stop asking about it and simply don't do it. :)

Comment: I remember you being a gentleman in answering my question once. So, I'll respect your word on this one.

Comment: Anyways, how do I fix it? Like by having the destructor virtual in the base class?

Comment: @Southee: Yes, like that.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Let's assume that the base destructor is not virtual. Does this cause memory leak, "*

Easily, yes. If `Derived` holds some dynamically allocated memory that should be deleted with it's destructor.

> *"if yes, why?"*

See explanation above. `Derived`'s destructor won't be called.

> *"And what would be the solution to fix it?"*

Make the `Base` class destructor `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose that both classes has trivial destructor but Derived class has member with non trivial destructor that Base has not. (std::vector for example) that would leak memory, because destructor of vector will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no dynamic member data in the `Base` class, it won't cause a memory leak. Still reeks of smell. A code smell.